# INVITE request not going when trying to make call from PJSIP ios

Tags: ios, sip, pjsip

I am trying to make a SIP call app for ios for which I am using PJSIP as the client. I have Kamailio SIP server running on cloud. I am not able to make audio/video call from my pjsip client. But if I try from other third party apps I am able to receive the call with 200 OK and video and audio works fine in that case. I am logging each INVITE request in my server. So when I am trying to make a call from the pjsip client it's not being logged there, that means it never reached the server. But if I try other apps the INVITE request is being logged correctly.

The code I have tried is like below. What can be wrong in this?

```
pj_str_t uri = pj_str("sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>");
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    pjsua_call_id p_call_id;
    pjsua_call_setting opt;

    pjsua_call_setting_default(&opt);

    opt.vid_cnt = 1;
    opt.aud_cnt = 1;

    pjsua_msg_data msg_data;
    pjsua_msg_data_init(&msg_data);

    pj_status_t status = pjsua_call_make_call(appDelegate.accountId , &uri, 0, NULL, &msg_data, &p_call_id);
    if(status == PJ_SUCCESS){
        NSLog(@"call made successfully from %d with callID %d",appDelegate.accountId,p_call_id);
        if(pjsua_call_is_active(p_call_id)) {
            NSLog(@"call is active");
        }
    }else {
        NSLog(@"call made failed");
    }
```

Account is registered correctly but not able to call any SIP URI.

Below is the log which is being done by pjsip in XCode

```
11:43:02.678           pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #0 to sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>
11:43:02.678            pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
11:43:02.678            pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
11:43:02.678        coreaudio_dev.c  ...Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
11:43:03.182        coreaudio_dev.c  ...core audio stream started
11:43:03.191          pjsua_media.c  .Call 1: initializing media..
11:43:03.192          pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 192.168.1.185:4004
11:43:03.192          pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 192.168.1.185:4005
11:43:03.192          pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 192.168.1.185:4006
11:43:03.192          pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 192.168.1.185:4007
11:43:03.193          pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 1
11:43:03.193         tsx0x102061ca8  ....Temporary failure in sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=12090 (tdta0x102022ca8), will try next server: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT)
11:43:03.193           pjsua_core.c  ....TX 1350 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=12090 (tdta0x102022ca8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
INVITE sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjlK38zIfNAOehpCfRHKJsAhPsYYBgcZwm

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12090 INVITE

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   726



v=0

o=- 3771123183 3771123183 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

s=pjmedia

b=AS:386

t=0 0

a=X-nat:0

m=audio 4004 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 120 96

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:96000

a=rtcp:4005 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

a=fmtp:104 mode=30

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:120 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:120 useinbandfec=1

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16

m=video 4006 RTP/AVP 97

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:256000

a=rtcp:4007 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1


--end msg--
11:43:03.202                    APP  .......Call 1 state=CALLING
2019-07-03 11:43:03.202285+0530 AnuranRealSIPOBJ[682:115773] call made successfully from 0 with callID 1
2019-07-03 11:43:03.202354+0530 AnuranRealSIPOBJ[682:115773] call is active
11:43:03.205         os_core_unix.c  Info: possibly re-registering existing thread
11:43:03.445           pjsua_core.c  .RX 520 bytes Response msg 407/INVITE/cseq=12090 (rdata0x102057828) from UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport=<MY_PORT>;branch=z9hG4bKPjlK38zIfNAOehpCfRHKJsAhPsYYBgcZwm;received=103.78.19.70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>;tag=74470fdebd33581b6e08c1006f836cbf.6a7c

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12090 INVITE

Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIm10cR28skgjbrHj/f+9ZPGsArPEh"

Server: kamailio (4.4.7 (x86_64/linux))

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
11:43:03.445           pjsua_core.c  ..TX 373 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=12090 (tdta0x101865ea8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
ACK sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjlK38zIfNAOehpCfRHKJsAhPsYYBgcZwm

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>;tag=74470fdebd33581b6e08c1006f836cbf.6a7c

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12090 ACK

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
11:43:03.445           pjsua_core.c  .......TX 1543 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=12091 (tdta0x102022ca8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
INVITE sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjS73qa.6dveexSsi-gdxX6zxCB0dP.kDv

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12091 INVITE


Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIm10cR28skgjbrHj/f+9ZPGsArPEh", uri="sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>", response="8e9907cc0bb22f5a4f70f40c2f0c98a3"

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   726



v=0

o=- 3771123183 3771123183 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

s=pjmedia

b=AS:386

t=0 0

a=X-nat:0

m=audio 4004 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 120 96

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:96000

a=rtcp:4005 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

a=fmtp:104 mode=30

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:120 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:120 useinbandfec=1

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16

m=video 4006 RTP/AVP 97

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:256000

a=rtcp:4007 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1


--end msg--
11:43:03.946           pjsua_core.c  .TX 1543 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=12091 (tdta0x102022ca8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
INVITE sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjS73qa.6dveexSsi-gdxX6zxCB0dP.kDv

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12091 INVITE

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIm10cR28skgjbrHj/f+9ZPGsArPEh", uri="sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>", response="8e9907cc0bb22f5a4f70f40c2f0c98a3"

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   726



v=0

o=- 3771123183 3771123183 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

s=pjmedia

b=AS:386

t=0 0

a=X-nat:0

m=audio 4004 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 120 96

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:96000

a=rtcp:4005 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

a=fmtp:104 mode=30

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:120 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:120 useinbandfec=1

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16

m=video 4006 RTP/AVP 97

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:256000

a=rtcp:4007 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1


--end msg--
11:43:04.949           pjsua_core.c  .TX 1543 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=12091 (tdta0x102022ca8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
INVITE sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjS73qa.6dveexSsi-gdxX6zxCB0dP.kDv

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12091 INVITE

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIm10cR28skgjbrHj/f+9ZPGsArPEh", uri="sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>", response="8e9907cc0bb22f5a4f70f40c2f0c98a3"

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   726



v=0

o=- 3771123183 3771123183 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

s=pjmedia

b=AS:386

t=0 0

a=X-nat:0

m=audio 4004 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 120 96

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:96000

a=rtcp:4005 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

a=fmtp:104 mode=30

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:120 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:120 useinbandfec=1

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16

m=video 4006 RTP/AVP 97

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:256000

a=rtcp:4007 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1


--end msg--
11:43:06.950           pjsua_core.c  .TX 1543 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=12091 (tdta0x102022ca8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
INVITE sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjS73qa.6dveexSsi-gdxX6zxCB0dP.kDv

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12091 INVITE

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIm10cR28skgjbrHj/f+9ZPGsArPEh", uri="sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>", response="8e9907cc0bb22f5a4f70f40c2f0c98a3"

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   726



v=0

o=- 3771123183 3771123183 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

s=pjmedia

b=AS:386

t=0 0

a=X-nat:0

m=audio 4004 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 120 96

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:96000

a=rtcp:4005 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

a=fmtp:104 mode=30

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:120 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:120 useinbandfec=1

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16

m=video 4006 RTP/AVP 97

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:256000

a=rtcp:4007 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1


--end msg--
11:43:10.711           pjsua_core.c  .TX 525 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=53776 (tdta0x10186aea8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
REGISTER sip:<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjRndxjb7QxFtX.qSuAum124WbvCVkKmG8

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>;tag=CeJ4HMtIf04gAl.YecQDR8ozwv3xwKJc

To: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>

Call-ID: nxID29ven.jgvKV2BBs-Uy-mFXBfTZ8Z

CSeq: 53776 REGISTER

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Expires: 10

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
11:43:10.933           pjsua_core.c  .RX 508 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=53776 (rdata0x101868e28) from UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport=<MY_PORT>;branch=z9hG4bKPjRndxjb7QxFtX.qSuAum124WbvCVkKmG8;received=103.78.19.70

From: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>;tag=CeJ4HMtIf04gAl.YecQDR8ozwv3xwKJc

To: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>;tag=74470fdebd33581b6e08c1006f836cbf.8cd0

Call-ID: nxID29ven.jgvKV2BBs-Uy-mFXBfTZ8Z

CSeq: 53776 REGISTER

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIol0cR3aDCkiTUKZEDF1gfQkJ7746"

Server: kamailio (4.4.7 (x86_64/linux))

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
11:43:10.934           pjsua_core.c  ....TX 708 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=53777 (tdta0x10186aea8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
REGISTER sip:<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjLmjahOVyW1Oe5rfU9Ld1lWeGagFLu6-X

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>;tag=CeJ4HMtIf04gAl.YecQDR8ozwv3xwKJc

To: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>

Call-ID: nxID29ven.jgvKV2BBs-Uy-mFXBfTZ8Z

CSeq: 53777 REGISTER

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Expires: 10

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIol0cR3aDCkiTUKZEDF1gfQkJ7746", uri="sip:<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>", response="41971a38daef9fac0d2519f0e90dc26c"

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
11:43:10.950           pjsua_core.c  .TX 1543 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=12091 (tdta0x102022ca8) to UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
INVITE sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT> SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjS73qa.6dveexSsi-gdxX6zxCB0dP.kDv

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:1001@<MY_IP>;tag=ll1r5bccrs7o9.Y24PntSkfvusfNGjSa

To: sip:901@<MY_IP>

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>

Call-ID: UO0bmgkIaqC-svFw1ZmsULsGqnwP9qke

CSeq: 12091 INVITE

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

User-Agent: AnuranRealSIPObj

Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="<MY_IP>", nonce="XRxIm10cR28skgjbrHj/f+9ZPGsArPEh", uri="sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>", response="8e9907cc0bb22f5a4f70f40c2f0c98a3"

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   726



v=0

o=- 3771123183 3771123183 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

s=pjmedia

b=AS:386

t=0 0

a=X-nat:0

m=audio 4004 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 120 96

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:96000

a=rtcp:4005 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

a=fmtp:104 mode=30

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:120 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:120 useinbandfec=1

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16

m=video 4006 RTP/AVP 97

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.185

b=TIAS:256000

a=rtcp:4007 IN IP4 192.168.1.185

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e; packetization-mode=1


--end msg--
11:43:11.184           pjsua_core.c  .RX 459 bytes Response msg 200/REGISTER/cseq=53777 (rdata0x102057828) from UDP <MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>:
SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;rport=<MY_PORT>;branch=z9hG4bKPjLmjahOVyW1Oe5rfU9Ld1lWeGagFLu6-X;received=103.78.19.70

From: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>;tag=CeJ4HMtIf04gAl.YecQDR8ozwv3xwKJc

To: <sip:1001@<MY_IP>>;tag=74470fdebd33581b6e08c1006f836cbf.91a1

Call-ID: nxID29ven.jgvKV2BBs-Uy-mFXBfTZ8Z

CSeq: 53777 REGISTER

Contact: <sip:1001@103.78.19.70:<MY_PORT>;ob>;expires=60

Server: kamailio (4.4.7 (x86_64/linux))

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
11:43:11.184            pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP outbound status for acc 0 is not active
11:43:11.184            pjsua_acc.c  ....sip:1001@<MY_IP>: registration success, status=200 (OK), will re-register in 60 seconds
11:43:11.184            pjsua_acc.c  ....Keep-alive timer started for acc 0, destination:<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>, interval:30s
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

From the traces, `sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>` is not a valid **URI** for sure; you have to replace the placeholders (`<xxx>`) with valid values.

> Temporary failure in sending Request ...: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT)
>   Request msg INVITE/cseq=12090 (tdta0x102022ca8) to **UDP** `<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>`:
>
> INVITE `sip:901@<MY_IP>:<MY_PORT>` SIP/2.0

Comment: I know that. I obscured those because of security issue.

Comment: ;So the traces are misleading! Difficult to say but I expect that the request uri should be something like sip:901@dns-fqdn without IP and port ; then add decorated URI for transport TCP sip:901@sipserver.net;transport=tcp and resolve the IP like sip:901@10.0.0.2;transport=tcp. You get the method I think you start from a generic URI and add changes one by one.